# Empty state page and Navigator issues?

Tags: dart, flutter, future, flutter-navigation

I want to implement [empty state page](https://material.io/design/communication/empty-states.html#content) in Flutter app, when news feed is empty.

When there is no activity in feed, I want to show **‘no activity’**. When database has data, I want to load this from `StreamBuilder` to `ListView.builder`

I try implement with:

```
child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: collection.snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {

    if(snapshot.hasData) {
       return ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                build(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
         );
      } else {
          return _emptyStateWidget();
      }
```

I must return something in else statement because sometimes snapshot will not have data so will throw error that Widget return null.

But this is causing issues with widget tree. Because if I try to use Navigator.push in `build` Widget later:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
…
FlatButton(
  onPressed: () async {

await function(document);

if(validated == true) {
await Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (BuildContext context) =>
    new Screen(documentInfo: documentInfo)));
}
```

Error is thrown:

> Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe. At this point
>   the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable. To safely
>   refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference
>   to the ancestor by calling inheritFromWidgetOfExactType() in the
>   widget's didChangeDependencies() method.

Is there way to avoid this so that no error is thrown?

For some reason if I call `Navigator.push` before await `function(document)` there is no error thrown. But I cannot allow this because it must perform data validation in function before and only navigate if success.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

After more test I think problem is cause by `StreamBuilder`. It rebuild whenever it get new event. So this cause issue when call `Navigator.push` and it get new event so try to rebuild.

How to solve? Is possible to stop `StreamBuilder` from rebuild descendant?

Comment: For empty state return `new Container()` so that it won't give any errors.

And for `onPressed` event try putting the `Navigation.push` inside `itemBuilder` itself by saving the `documentInfo` in `var` or anything you want.

Comment: Thanks for reply! What you mean put `Navigation.push` in `itemBuilder`?

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are trying to navigate to somewhere else while your widget tree is still being built.

You should move the `Navigation.push` to a stream listener, for example, in your `initState`.

```
void initState() {
super.initState();
collection.snapshots.listen((data){

if(validated == true) {
   await Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) =>
      new Screen(documentInfo: documentInfo)));
  }
});

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! But `validated` is not from database. It is result of operation perform on data taken from database

Comment: I couldn't find the `validated` within your code, but basically that's not the idea to retain here but instead how you should deal with `Navigator` with streams.

Comment: Thanks. But `validated` is `bool`. I am try use stream but no think can use stream on `bool`?

Comment: I am have try use you method but cannot see how to add you stream to my `StreamBuilder`. How to do?